# USB modem gets disconnected after some time in 12.04

Tags: usb-modem, huawei, modem-manager

I have huawei E1732 USB modem and I am using mobile-partner with it(given by the manufacturer).
Recently the modem began to disconnect and the network doesn't show up after it disconnects and I have to remove it and reinsert it to make it work.
What should I do to prevent it from disconnecting again frequently?
Also is there any way to control my USB modem using the terminal?
tail -n100 syslog gave the following output:
tail -n100 syslog

```
Aug 21 17:58:24 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:24 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
Aug 21 17:58:25 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:25 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
Aug 21 17:58:25 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:25 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
Aug 21 17:58:26 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:26 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
Aug 21 17:58:26 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:26 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
Aug 21 17:58:27 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:27 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
Aug 21 17:58:27 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:27 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
Aug 21 17:58:28 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:28 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
Aug 21 17:58:28 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:28 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
Aug 21 17:58:29 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:29 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
Aug 21 17:58:29 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:29 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
Aug 21 17:58:30 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:30 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
Aug 21 17:58:30 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:30 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
Aug 21 17:58:31 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:31 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
Aug 21 17:58:31 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:31 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
Aug 21 17:58:32 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:32 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
Aug 21 17:58:32 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:32 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
Aug 21 17:58:33 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:33 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
Aug 21 17:58:33 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:33 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
Aug 21 17:58:34 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:34 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
Aug 21 17:58:34 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:34 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
Aug 21 17:58:35 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:35 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
Aug 21 17:58:35 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:35 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
Aug 21 17:58:36 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:36 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
Aug 21 17:58:36 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:36 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
Aug 21 17:58:37 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:37 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
Aug 21 17:58:37 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:37 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
Aug 21 17:58:38 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:38 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
Aug 21 17:58:38 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:38 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
Aug 21 17:58:39 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:39 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
Aug 21 17:58:39 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:39 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
Aug 21 17:58:40 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:40 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
Aug 21 17:58:40 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:40 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
Aug 21 17:58:41 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:41 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
Aug 21 17:58:41 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:41 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
Aug 21 17:58:42 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:42 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
Aug 21 17:58:42 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:42 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
Aug 21 17:58:43 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:43 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
Aug 21 17:58:43 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:43 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
Aug 21 17:58:44 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:44 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
Aug 21 17:58:44 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:44 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
Aug 21 17:58:45 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:45 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
Aug 21 17:58:45 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:45 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
Aug 21 17:58:46 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:46 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
Aug 21 17:58:46 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:46 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
Aug 21 17:58:47 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:47 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
Aug 21 17:58:47 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:47 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
Aug 21 17:58:48 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:48 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
Aug 21 17:58:48 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:48 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
Aug 21 17:58:49 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() entry.
Aug 21 17:58:49 sony-VPCEH15EN MobilePartner.bin: ndis_get_status() exit.
```

Comment: Its helpful for us if you share logs when its disconnected by using following commands `cd /var/log; tail -n100 syslog`

Comment: Is your modem can be seen on the output of ``lsusb`` when it's disconnected.

Comment: It is safe to run it was written by me and some good friends it will help diagnose your wireless issue.
Paste this command in a terminal  `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script` 
It will download a script and create a file named (wireless-info.txt, or wireless-info.txt.tar.gz) in your home folder paste the file here http://pastebin.com/ then paste the link back here.